# How to hide keyboard from EditText after finish writing without lost the text

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-edittext, kotlin

Hell, I have a ListView with adapter when the app start the code put a EditText in my ListView after click in the EditText I can't write so I tried to solve this problem I did a focus and it's work fine and the app allow me to write but after done writing and I hide the keyboard the text will gone.

I wan't this editText to be normally like any other EditText when I clicked in I writed when I click done, the keyboard gone and my text stay there. How should I do that?

```
var List=ArrayList<Ticket>()
var adapter:ListAdabter?=null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act2)

    List.add(Ticket("1"))
    adapter=ListAdabter(this,List)
    listview.adapter=adapter
}

fun View.showKeyboard() {
    this.requestFocus()
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}

inner class ListAdabter :BaseAdapter{
    var ListLocal = ArrayList<Ticket>()
    var mCtx:Context?=null

    constructor(mCtx:Context,List:ArrayList<Ticket>):super(){
        this.ListLocal=List
        this.mCtx=mCtx
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val item = ListLocal[position]
        val layoutInf = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val view = layoutInf.inflate(R.layout.add_ticket,null)
        val edit = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.txtDes)
        edit.requestFocus()
        edit.showKeyboard()  //The Problem is Here 
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return ListLocal[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
       return ListLocal.size
    }

}
```

Comment: i lost my text on the EditText(Cleans himself) after i hide the keyboard

Comment: Is the EditText showing after hiding keyboard?

Comment: Yeah i can tap in and write again but every time i click done when i finshe or i hide the keyboard i lost my text (Cleans himself)